# Detecting steganography in JPG, PNG, and BMP

Tags: steganography

I have a little problem about my research on steganography.
For short, I used StegSpy 2.1 to run a test for my stego images. I used 9 JPG images, 9 BMP images, and 9 PNG images.
From all of them, there are 5 stego images that detected has steganography in it. 3 from PNG files, 1 from JPG, and 1 from BMP.
The problem is, my mentor asked me about how come the PNG files got the most detected files than JPG and BMP. I don't know how to answer.
Can anyone help me about that?

Comment: sounds like your mentor wants you to research exactly how messages can be hidden in each format, what the differences are and why some of those previously mentioned categories might make messages hidden in images easier to identify.

Comment: What are the expected results? Is there a message in all of them ? Do you know the steganographic method used for each of them ?

Comment: As per @Nalaurien's comment, dig deeper into the analysis, here's an article that mentions methods used for detection you can study further: https://www.darknet.org.uk/2014/09/stegexpose-steganalysis-tool-detecting-steganography-images/